# Rust deserialize a number represented as string in a JSON into a struct

Tags: rust, deserialization, rust-cargo, serde

I am a newbie to the rust and having trouble deserializing a json string into a struct. What I want is to deserialize the following json string,

```
{
   "ratelimit_limit": "10",
   "ratelimit_remaining": "0",
   "ratelimit_reset": "30s"
}
```

into the following struct.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
#[serde(default)]
struct FilterConfig {
   
    ratelimit_limit: u16,

    ratelimit_remaining: u16,

    #[serde(with = "serde_humanize_rs")]
    ratelimit_reset: Duration,
}
```

The problem comes when I try to deserialize a string into u16. I think the issue is with implicit conversions which are removed from serde. https://github.com/serde-rs/json/issues/317

The solution that is mentioned in that issue does not provide a clean solution. It uses a custom deserializer to deseralize u16 feilds. Is there any easier straightforward solution to this ?? It should be a very common use case.

Comment: https://docs.rs/serde-aux/2.2.0/serde_aux/field_attributes/fn.deserialize_number_from_string.html

Comment: If you need support for serializing or for nesting (i.e., `Vec<u16>`) this type works well https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.9.1/serde_with/struct.DisplayFromStr.html

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks a lot. Exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @jonasbb Thank you. I will go through it and see. Now I'm using the crate that peter mentioned and it works perfectly.